# Sublime text 2: how do you activate Replace after a find in files with keyboard shortcuts only?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext

On osX, if you File > Find in Files... ⇧⌘F you're brought to the Find Results.
There you enter the 'find' field, Tab, Tab, 'replace' field.

My problem is how you can activate 'Replace' once you have done that without using a mouse to click the button.
If you press Tab from there it goes back to top line, and if you press enter it just performs a normal find.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I guess this helps you , check to this [shortcuts](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html)

Comment: Nope sorry, they do not mention the shortcut i need, just the main find in files shortcut

Answer (score 0):

This one should activate the find and replace window ( **⌘ + ⌥ + F** )

This one is like clicking the replace button once you fill the fields ( **⌘ + ⌥ + E** )

let me know if it works

Comment: Nope, it works as a normal replace for the currently opened window only, not for all files in the directory selected :)